# Python: optional group in regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse HTML `img` tags in a certain document, in particular I want to find all `src`, `alt` and `title` attributes of an image. Attributes are always in the same order, however `title` and `alt` **are optional**, they could be absent.

I've tried to make groups optional with `(?:title="(.*?)")?` in my regular expression, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
example = '<img class="alignnone wp-image-4170 size-full" title="example_title" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/example.jpg" alt="example_alt" width="300" height="430" />'
re.search(r'(?:title="(.*?)")?.*?src="(.*?)".*?(?:alt="(.*?)")?', example).groups()
>>> (None, 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/example.jpg', None)
```

Expected result would be:

```
('example_title', 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/example.jpg', 'example_alt')
```

Comment: Are you using regex just as a learning exercise? Because parsing HTML with regex should be avoided. You should use a proper parser for this.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: @idjaw, I agree, but in my case using something like beautifulsoup module would be an overkill. I just want to parse some short blog posts.

Comment: @BrenBarn added that to the question

Comment: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. Is that what you really want?

Comment: @TammoHeeren I'm not sure. I use it with question mark on the end to make the whole thing optional. There are images without titles and alts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the title to match by moving your first `.*?` inside your first non-capturing group:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?:title="(.*?)".*?)?src="(.*?)".*?(?:alt="(.*?)")?', example).groups()
('example_title',
 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/example.jpg',
 None)
```

The problem with your regex is that it includes .* after an optional group.  This means that right at the beginning of the string, the regex is "allowed" to not match the optional group (since it's optional), and instead move on to match what comes after it.  Since what comes after it is `.*?`, which will match anything, this always succeeds, and it has no need to match your title group.  It just uses the `.*?` to match everything from the beginning of the string up to the "src", and then matches the "src".  Moving the `.*?` inside the non-capturing group forces it to not match the "anything" unless it first matches the title; then it will only match the "src" if it advances its search position all the way there without finding the title first.

As was mentioned in a comment, parsing HTML this way is not a great idea.  Your question is actually an illustration of why.  When you wrote `(?:title="(.*?)")?.*?` you probably were thinking in terms of "an optional title followed by anything", but the problem is that the "anything" can also include a title, so what it actually means is "either a title right at the beginning of the string and followed by anything, or just anything (including a title that we will ignore)".  When you try to combine specific matches like `title=` with generic matches like `.*`, what you are trying to capture may be slurped up by a `.*` instead of captured with your more specific group.  In addition, your code assumes that title, src, and alt will always occur in that order, but they may occur in any order, in which case your regex will fail to capture them correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're right, moving .*? inside non-capturing groups really helped. Also, thank you for your in-depth explanation, I guess I have to learn a lot about regexes :)